# Store reset while query was in flight (not completed in link chain)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

in React using graphql, There is this issue I face where I get prompted with

> Store reset while query was in flight (not completed in link chain)

when I log out my user.

the code is

```
  const onSignout = async () => {
    removeToken();
    client.cache.reset();
    await client.resetStore();
    history.push('/');
  };
```

I followed the many issues on github like
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3766

and changed to

```
client.stop();
client.cache.reset();
client.resetStore();
```

but still happen

I checked the network, no query are pending when login out.

similar : [Preventing: Store reset while query was in flight (not completed in link chain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59497574/preventing-store-reset-while-query-was-in-flight-not-completed-in-link-chain)

Comment: were you able to solve it? and if yes, could you post your solution here please. I have the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

What I've found caused this is that the `resetStore` causes all queries to be refetched per the documentation, which if you then have a rerender that causes the resetStore call to be called again, you then have reset the store while the queries where in flight.

What I did to resolve this was a few things:

1. Don't use `resetStore`. Use `clearStore` (their documentation suggests this if you don't intend to have the queries refetched)
2. Implement some kind of idempotency control on the logout mechanism. As a naive example

```
const AuthenticatedComponent = () => {
  const [isLoggingOut, setIsLoggingOut] = useState(false);
  const client = useApolloClient();
  
  const logout = () => {
    if (!isLoggingOut) {
      // or whatever business logic you use to invalidate session
      deleteSession(); 
      client.clearStore();
      setIsLoggingOut(true);
    }
  };
  return (<>
    { /* Whatever else */ }
    <button onClick={logout}> Log Out </button>
  </>)
}
```